# Disjoint sets of rationals both dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

There exists a pair of disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that both are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
True or false?

The statement is true but how can I find an example of such disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: What have you thought of? What examples have you tried?

Comment: Is$(\frac{m}{2^k})_{m, k}$ dense?

Comment: Are m and k integers? Then this is dense in R.

Comment: First I took example - A = {m/2^k, m - Z , k - N union 0} and B = { m/3^k, m - z, k - N union 0}

Comment: You're looking more generally for ways to partition $\mathbb{Q}$ into pieces *not* based on size (e.g. you don't want $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb{Q}$ versus $(\sqrt{2},\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$). The two obvious places to look for a distinction to draw are **numerator** and **denominator**. For example, we could let $EN$ be the set of rationals which (in lowest terms) have an even numerator. Or, we could let $DD$ be the set of rationals whose denominator (in lowest terms) is a power of $2$ ("dyadic" fractions). Or, so on. (cont'd)

Comment: Do you see any way to divide up the rationals based on what their numerator or denominator (HINT: it will probably be easier to think about the denominators) into pieces which are each dense?

Comment: A = {m/2^k, m - Z , k - N union 0} and B = { m/3^k, m - z, k - N union 0}. Both are dense in R. Are they disjoint? Since 1 is in both sets. In A, if m = 4 and k = 2 and in B , if m = 9, k = 3, we get that 1 is in both sets. So how could they be disjoint?

Comment: Your example of $A=\left\{\frac{m}{2^k}: m\in \mathbb Z, k \in \mathbb N \cup 0\right\}$, $B=\left\{\frac{m}{3^k}: m\in \mathbb Z, k \in \mathbb N \cup 0\right\}$ is a good idea but for example $\frac{20}{2^2}=\frac{15}{3^1}$ so you need to exclude cases like these.

Comment: If I exclude integers from this set then?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: So i need to exclude Z from either both A and B or anyone.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now,

$$
0 < 2^nx - [2^nx] < 1
$$

and thus

$$
0 < x - \frac{[2^nx]}{2^n} <  \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

This says that $D = \{\frac{m}{2^n}\}_{m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, let's consider a subset of this set,

$$
A = \{\frac{m}{2^n} : n \in \mathbb{N}, m \in \mathbb{Z} , 2 \not |n \}
$$

If $A$ were dense in $D$, it would be dense in $\mathbb{R}$. For this, we only have to show that $D \setminus A$ can be approximated by elements of $A$. Let $\frac{m}{2^n} \in D \setminus A$ and write $m = 2^ks$ with $2 \not | s$. It can't be that $k \leq n$, because that would mean $\frac{m}{2^n} = \frac{s}{2^{n-k}} \in A$. Therefore, $k \geq n$ and thus $\frac{m}{2^n} = 2^{k-n}s \in \mathbb{Z}$. This means that it is sufficient to show that $A$ can approximate integers: if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, then taking $\frac{1}{2^n} < \varepsilon$ we have that

$$
\left|a - \frac{2^na + 1}{2^n}\right| = \frac{1}{2^n} < \varepsilon
$$

and $\frac{2^na + 1}{2^n} \in A$ because $2 \not | \  2^na+1$. In conclusion, we have shown that $A$ is dense in $D$ and since $D$ is dense in the reals, so is $A$. With an identical construction (which I encourage you to write out) one can show that the same holds for

$$
B = \{\frac{m}{3^n} : n \in \mathbb{N}, m \in \mathbb{Z} , 3 \not |n \}
$$

To conclude, then, we just have to observe that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. In effect, if

$$
\frac{m}{2^n} = \frac{j}{3^k}
$$

for some $n,m,j,k$, then $3^km = 2^nj$ and thus $2 | 2^nj = 3^km$. But since $2$ and $3$ are coprime, this would imply $2 | m$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-It is enough to show an example in $I=[0,1]$. All rational is periodic after a finite number of digits
$$r=0.a_1a_2....a_m[b_1b_2....b_n]\in I$$ It is not hard to prove that $A$ and $B$ below are disjoint and dense in $I$

$$A=\{r\text{ such that }  b_n=1\}\\B=\{r\text{ such that }  b_n\ne1\}$$